# How do I get an FileInputStream from FileItem in java?

Tags: java, inputstream, java-io, fileitem

I am trying to avoid the FileItem `getInputStream()`, because it will get the wrong encoding, for that I need a `FileInputStream` instead. Is there any way to get a FileInputStream without using this method? Or can I transform my fileitem into a file?

```
if (this.strEncoding != null && !this.strEncoding.isEmpty()) {
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clsFile.getInputStream(), this.strEncoding));
} 
else {
    // br = ?????
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you can share sample code.

Comment: Are you talking about FileItem from Apache commons?

Comment: An `InputStream` has no encoding in Java; it deals with `byte`s. Going from an `InputStream` to a `Reader` generally involves defining an encoding, but that's not a Stream issue. If the way you obtain your `InputStream` infers with the encoding you get, then I suspect something undefined / strange / default / platform specific is at work, which may later turn into a bug.

Comment: What is the file type? Is it plain text file or binary file?

Comment: As @GPI said, you have a misunderstanding, as an `InputStream` does not have an encoding. Show us the code you are using that is reading from `FileItem.getInputStream()` and we can tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: example:

if ( this.strEncoding != null && !this.strEncoding.isEmpty () )
{
   br = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader ( clsFile.getInputStream (), this.strEncoding ) );
}
else
{
    ?????????????
}

Answer (score 2):

You can try

[FileItem#getString(encoding)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29)

> Returns the contents of the file item as a String, using the specified encoding.

Comment: I dont have the encoding. can be anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `write` method here.

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file");
fileItem.write(file);
```

Comment: I did, just to pick a simple example. I could have easily typed it myself and still managed to write the same thing :)

Comment: No problem, I'll delete my comment now

Answer (score 0):

An InputStream is *binary data*, bytes. It must be converted to text by giving the encoding of those bytes.

Java uses internally Unicode to represent all text scripts. For text it uses String/char/Reader/Writer.

For binary data, byte[], InputStream, OutputStream.

So you could use a bridging class, like `InputStreamReader`:

```
String encoding = "UTF-8"; // Or "Windows-1252" ...
BufferedReader in = new BufferedStream(
    new InputStreamReader(fileItem.getInputStream(),
                          encoding));
```

Or if you read the bytes:

```
String s = new String(bytes, encoding);
```

The encoding is often an option parameter (there then exists an overloaded method without encoding).

Comment: There is a simple method `FileItem#getString()` if you are talking about text file. what about binary files. Can I use it for images?

Comment: You are right on getString (+1), though I felt called to pray about the schism between Binary and Text; as that _is_ what seems to be unclear, and likely erroneously used. Binary files should never be stored in String.

Comment: As per my knowledge `Reader` works for text stream only.

Comment: @Braj yes, you can use a ~Reader only to read text, and that seems to be the problem: there is resulting text in the wrong encoding. So a conversion of the binary file did not specify an encoding.

Comment: I dont have the encoding. can be anything

Comment: @Braj the getString will use the default encoding, and i dont know the encoding, can be anything

Comment: So you'll have to try out encodings. A dump of the byte values might help. Or some info on the language the text is in. Sorry.